Solr - Hadoop theory of data writing
I'm wondering how the data writing actually works.
In a Solr cluster that saves the indexes onto hadoop datanodes, if I instruct a shard splitting how is the data managed?
let's say that I split a collection across two solr nodes, but they forward the writing to the hadoop datanodes that write everything replicated, what will this produce?
Should I disable replication somewhere? or what?
I created and uploaded data in some collections, but just to test it. Unfortunately everything works fine and I couldn't notice particular hints on the situation.
Every suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Rob
